# how can i calculate the polynomial that has the following asymptotes

Tags: math

how can i calculate the polynomial that has the **tangent lines** (1) y = x where x  = 1, and (2) y = 1 where x = 365

I realize this may not be the proper forum but I figured somebody here could answer this in jiffy.

Also, I am not looking for an algorithm to answer this. I'd just like like to see the process.

Thanks.

**I guess I should have mentioned that i'm writing an algorithm for scaling the y-axis of flotr graph**

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net might be a worthy bookmark if you love Math.

Comment: no. i'm writing an algorithm for scaling the y-axis of flotr graph

Comment: @joshs The question itself a math question, no? I've reopened the question for now, but please try to keep future questions on the topic of programming.

Comment: @Jonathan: This question is probably too elementary for mathoverflow.

Comment: @joshs: Asymptotes or tangent line? Asymptotes aren't defined for only one point.

Comment: @Jonathan: mathoverflow is for research level maths, not high-school geometry. Many programmers have to deal with coordinate geometry, so this is certainly "of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification of the curve can be expressed as four constraints:

```
y(1)   = 1,     y'(1)   = 1      => tangent is (y=x) when x=1
y(365) = 1,     y'(365) = 0      => tangent is (y=1) when x=365
```

We therefore need a family of curves with at least four degrees of freedom to match these constraints; the simplest type of polynomial is a cubic,

```
y  = a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d
y' = 3*a*x^2 + 2*b*x + c
```

and the constraints give the following equations for the parameters:

```
a + b + c + d = 1
3*a + 2*b + c = 1
48627125*a + 133225*b + 365*c + d = 1
399675*a + 730*b + c = 0
```

I'm too old and too lazy to solve these myself, so I googled a [linear equation solver](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.html) to give the answer:

```
a = 1/132496, b = -731/132496, c = 133955/132496, d  = -729/132496
```

Answer (score 1):

I will post this type of question in mathoverflow.net next time. thanks

my solution in javascript was to adapt the equation of a circle:

```
        var radius = Math.pow((2*Math.pow(365, 2)), 1/2);
        var t = 365; //offset
        this.tMax = (Math.pow(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2), 1/2) - t) * (t / (r - t)) + 1;
```

the above equation has the above specified asymptotes. it is part of a step polynomial for scaling an axis for a flotr graph.

Comment: BTW, mathoverflow.net is not for simple maths questions. It is for researchers to appraise each other of what is currently known (or unknown)

Comment: And stackoverflow is for questions that are "of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere". Many, many programmers are interested in simple maths, particularly things like coordinate geometry.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are missing data (you need another point to determine the polynomial)

```
a*(x-1)^2+b*(x-1)+c=y-1
a*(x-365)^2+b*(x-365)+c=y-1
```

you can solve the exact answer for b
but A depends on C (or vv)

and your question is off topic anyways, and you need to revise your algebra

Comment: there is ample information there to determine a step function that meets those asymptotes. and, i'm doing this is part of a programming project